am3358 documentation question (addressable space vs memory map)
The AM3358 specs data sheet states that the processor has 1 GB of total addressable space. Looking at the memory map in the AM335x Technical Reference Manual, section 2:Memory Map, the address starts from 0x0 and ends at 0xFFFFFFFF which is a total of 4 GB. Maybe I'm confusing between two totally different concepts (addressable space & memory map) but I am having difficulty understanding why the processor doesn't have 4 GB of addressable space.

The reference to "1GB of Total Addressable Space" in the datasheet is referring specifically to the DRAM controller.  There's also half a GB allocated to the general purpose memory controller (usable with SRAM or Flash), and various smaller chunks that belong to the built-in RAM, ROM, and peripherals.  And there are numerous chunks that are simply marked "Reserved", and have no functionality.  All of these area fit within the CPU's 4GB address space.
